# How to specify which instance of an already loaded side-by-side assembly to use

Tags: windows, dll, transitive-dependency, activation-context-api

I am creating a dll (`A.dll`), which is isolated (`ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED`), depends on `dependency.dll` and has a manifest file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
    <assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
    <assemblyIdentity name="my.assembly.name" version="1.0.0.0" type="win32"/>
        <file name="A.dll"></file>
        <file name="dependency.dll"></file>
    </assembly>
```

`A.dll` is loaded by an application `app.exe`, which itself depends on a different version of `dependency.dll`. The manifest ensures that both versions  of `dependency.dll` are used side-by-side. No problem so far.

Now, `A.dll` loads another dll `B.dll` via `LoadLibrary`. `B.dll` is loaded from a foreign directory, depends on `dependency.dll` and actually needs to use the version of `dependency.dll` used by `A.dll`, which is already in memory.

The problem is that `B.dll` uses the version of `dependency.dll` used by `app.exe`, as this was the first version of a module with that name which has been loaded into memory.

Is there a way I can force `B.dll` to use the version of `dependency.dll` which has been loaded by `A.dll`?

Language is C++, if that's relevant.

Comment: Sounds like case for out-of-process invocation.

Comment: I'd like to avoid using a separate process if possible.

Comment: call from your *A.dll*  on `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` `GetCurrentActCtx(&ghActCtx)` and save context in global variable. before call `LoadLibrary(L"B.dll")` - call `ActivateActCtx(ghActCtx, &Cookie)` and `DeactivateActCtx(0, Cookie);` after call. `ReleaseActCtx(ghActCtx);` on `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't help. The system seems to ignore the activation context if there already is a module with the same name in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you can do this, but this would work in some of the cases where this comes up:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
    <assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
    <assemblyIdentity name="my.assembly.name" version="1.0.0.0" type="win32"/>
        <file name="A.dll"></file>
        <file name="B.dll"></file>
        <file name="dependency.dll"></file>
    </assembly>
```

If B.dll can't be made a static load because it is truly dynamically detected this won't work at all.

If the "same" requirement is really only "same version", you could make another assembly:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
    <assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
    <assemblyIdentity name="b.assembly.name" version="1.0.0.0" type="win32"/>
        <file name="B.dll"></file>
        <file name="dependency.dll"></file>
    </assembly>
```

If neither of these cases hold, you two choices remaining:

1) Do the out-of-process call.

2) Implement your own DLL loader and make the dependency resolution work the way you want. This won't help if B.DLL does LoadLibrary("dependency.dll") itself.